# SURF Feature extraction and Keypoint match based on FlannBasedMatcher

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Following is my code, which used to extract the features using SURF and which will match the points using flannBasedMatcher.

```
Mat object = imread("S6E0.bmp",  CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    if( !object.data )
    {
    // std::cout<< "Error reading object " << std::endl;
    return -2;
    }

    //Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector

    int minHessian = 500;

    SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );

    std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_object;

    detector.detect( object, kp_object );

    //Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
    SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

    Mat des_object;

    extractor.compute( object, kp_object, des_object );

    FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
    char key = 'a';
    //VideoCapture cap(0);

    namedWindow("Good Matches");

    std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);

    //Get the corners from the object
    obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0);
    obj_corners[1] = cvPoint( object.cols, 0 );
    obj_corners[2] = cvPoint( object.cols, object.rows );
    obj_corners[3] = cvPoint( 0, object.rows );

    Mat image = imread("S6E0.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat des_image, img_matches;

    std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_image;
    std::vector<vector<DMatch >> matches;

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch>> matches1;
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch>> matches2;
    std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches3;
    std::vector<DMatch > good_matches;
    std::vector<Point2f> obj;
    std::vector<Point2f> scene;

    std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);

    Mat H;

    //cvtColor(frame, image, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    detector.detect( image, kp_image );
    extractor.compute( image, kp_image, des_image );


    matcher.knnMatch(des_object, des_image, matches, 2);



    for(int i = 0; i < min(des_image.rows-1,(int) matches.size()); i++) //THIS LOOP IS SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
    {
        if((matches[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[i][1].distance)) && ((int) matches[i].size()<=2 && (int) matches[i].size()>0))
        {
            good_matches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
        }
    }

        //Draw only "good" matches

    drawMatches( object, kp_object, image, kp_image, good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1), vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );

    if (good_matches.size() >= 4)
    {
        printf("Images matching %d , %d", good_matches.size(), kp_object.size());

        //return 1;

        for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
        {

            //Get the keypoints from the good matches

            obj.push_back( kp_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
            scene.push_back( kp_image[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
        }

        //H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );
        //printf("Size : %d", H.size());
        //perspectiveTransform( obj_corners, scene_corners, H);
        //printf("Size : %d --- %d --- %d", H.size(), scene_corners.size()); 

    }else{

        printf("Images matching %d , %d", good_matches.size(), kp_object.size());
    }

        //Show detected matches

    imshow( "Good Matches", img_matches );
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
```

In this code i want to know what exactly happens through this method

```
matcher.knnMatch(des_object, des_image, matches, 2);
```

As i know i passes the two descriptors of the matching images and the **matches** vector is filled with 2 nearest neighbors. I want to know what exactly happens in the method and how the matches method is filled and what points are filled to it.

In this code segment

```
for(int i = 0; i < min(des_image.rows-1,(int) matches.size()); i++) //THIS LOOP IS SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
    {
        if((matches[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[i][1].distance)) && ((int) matches[i].size()<=2 && (int) matches[i].size()>0))
        {
            good_matches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
        }
    }
```

im using the nearest neibour distance ratio(nndr) as 0.6, i wanted to know how the good_matches are find out and how the nndr value change will effect.

It would be a great help, if i could resolve this code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **FlannBasedMatcher** is based on the paper written by [Muja et. al.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.160.1721); you can find the exact algorithm and how they go about it there..

Regarding the **good_matches**, you just saw in the code snippet itself that it is a collection of the *best matches* your result has based on the criteria, i.e., **nndr**.. It is basically a threshold that decides how far a match is allowed before dropping the match altogether.. Higher the threshold, more points are considered and more are the number of positive matches (whether they are **true positives** or not will be determined by your dataset and the way you have set the nndr level)..

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can u please explain the knnMatch(x,x,x) method, And are we saving the matched points in the matches vector?

Comment: Yes it is saving the matched points in `matched`vector. @scap3y told you that where the algorithm is taken from and you are still asking what does the method do. Go read that paper and figure out what and how does that method do what it is doing. Don't be lazy. Read.